# How to get rid of the empty items in match (regex operator | )?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var selectorText = "body" ; // first variant
// var selectorText = "div#id, div.body"; // multiple selector variant
// var selectorText = "div#id ul li, div.body"; // multiple selector variant
var C1 = selectorText.match(/(^|\s|,)\w+($|[\s,#\.:\[])/); // element
var C = !C1 ? 0 : C1.length;
```

How to make it that the result C is 1 in the case if single selector "body" and C to be 2 in the case of the multiple selector variant with the element selectors?

Current result with "body" is 3 (two empty items). I need to get rid of the empty items in the array to get correct count of elements (body, div, ul, li). I know that the empty items are created because of use the alternative operator | in brackets on begin and on end of the regex. But how to get rid of of the empty items?

Comment: why don't you filter the resulting array ?

Comment: It would be simpler to make correct regex. But the idea of filtering is good so I could try if there is no other way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) returns

> An Array containing the entire match result and any
>   parentheses-captured matched results; null if there were no matches.

So you should change those capturing groups to non-capturing groups in addition to using global `g` modifier:

```
> "body".match(/(?:^|\s|,)\w+(?:$|[\s,#\.:\[])/g).length;
< 1
```

```
> "div#id, div.body".match(/(?:^|\s|,)\w+(?:$|[\s,#\.:\[])/g).length;
< 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Include the **`g`** flag.

From [match method description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

> If the regular expression does not include the g flag, returns the
>   same result as [RegExp.exec()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec).

Answer (score 1):

The `String.prototype.match()` method returns an array so you can use the `Array.prototype.map()` method to remove the empty items (that is; return the non-empty items).

```
var regex = /(^|\s|,)\w+($|[\s,#\.:\[])/;
var C1 = selectorText.match(regex).map(function(item){
    if ( item != "" ) return item;
});
```

See: [Array.prototype.map() @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)